# Does this Hampton Bay ceiling fan have a capacitor inside the motor housing?

Tags: ceiling-fan, electric-motor

I have an older Hampton Bay ["Andross"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009M99PNI) ceiling fan which only turns very slowly now (one of the kids fessed-up to using it as a catapult for their stuffed animals). I can't find this model for sale anywhere so wondering if I can replace the motor, or the start capacitor. I took the thing apart to find the start capacitor, which I thought might be inside the motor. I don't think it is. The two "shells" on the motor seem to be pressed on along with bearings. They don't want to come apart. Anyone know if this motor has the capacitor inside the gray wireless module?

[image]

Comment: Possible the stuff animals and the fan being slow are two separate things that happen at the same time.  Might find on google the service/wiring manual for that make and model.

Comment: Might find that there is no such thing as a "service manual" for this. Far too many items are made to be disposable, not repaired.

Comment: @crip659, I can't find too much blame for the kid. I bet it was a good time while it lasted. It would have been for me too at that age. Anyway, yeah, not sure which one caused it. I've tried looking for the MT-515 model and nothing comes up. I suppose I could take the module apart and see if there's a cap inside.

Comment: Imagine the kid only did what we wish we could do.  Don't think a regular stuff toy would do it, unless done for an excessive time(hours).

Comment: @isherwood `Anyone know if this motor has the capacitor inside the gray wireless module ? `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it the the capacitor goes in the switch housing, or light kit (not pictured) which connects to the 6-way plug at the bottom of the photo.

if you pull on the black, white, and blue wires  you'll find that they pass through the motor axle without making any internal connections,

It's the orange, yellow, and red wires that go to the motor and they  have the capacitor connected.

Comment: Thanks for this! It was in the switch housing just as you said. Buried under a blob of wiring and I didn't even see it.

Answer (score 2):

My best shot at an answer to the question whether the grey wireless module has a capacitor inside:

It does most likely not have a capacitor for the fan motor inside. I've had a few fans with an identical looking wireless module. Since all of my fan outlets are run with separate switched hots for light and fan, I preferred to use the wall switches instead of a remote. So I just wired the fan up directly without the wireless module, and everything worked normally. I am even using a fan speed control wall switch to control the speed.

But this leads to a troubleshooting step you could use: Since you said the fan only runs very slowly, you could try to wire it up without the wireless module. Maybe it has somehow become stuck on slow speed. If the fan runs at "full" speed when wired direct, you know you have a bad wireless module (or maybe even bad remote).

Comment: I hadn't thought of bypassing the wireless module. Good idea and worth a shot!